# How do I create a MeteorJS project in IntelliJ?

Tags: templates, meteor, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I would like to create a MeteorJS project in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.1, but it is not showing up in the "New Projects" template:

[image]

I have MeteorJS installed and running elsewhere, but I'm unable to find a way to create a MeteorJS project through IDEA.

It's [definitely supported](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-meteor.html), so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Meteor plugin is not part of IDEA by default.

[Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7549?pr=idea) it says:

> Note: The plugin is a part of WebStorm IDE and you don't need install it manually for WebStorm

If you are not using WebStorm you should install the plugin.

You can do this by doing the following:

> Go to the Preferences menu (CMD , in OSX)
>
> Click the "Plugins" section in the left pane
>
> Click "Install Jetbrains plugin..." in the right panel in the lower
>   left
>
> Search for "Meteor" in the search box
>
> Click "Install plugin" in the right box

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction.  If you'd be willing to put the steps to add the plugin, I'll mark this as correct